# Fast way to check the biggest variable?

Tags: javascript

I need a way to get the name of the variable with the greatest value.

```
a = 55;
b = 13;
c = 45;
d = 5;

var top = '';
if((a>b)&&(a>c)&&(a>d)){ top = 'a'; }
if((b>a)&&(b>c)&&(b>d)){ top = 'b'; }
if((c>a)&&(c>b)&&(c>d)){ top = 'c'; }
if((d>a)&&(d>b)&&(d>c)){ top = 'd'; }
```

Is there a better or faster way to do this?

Comment: Why do you need the variable name as **string** in `top`? Add complete code.

Comment: is there not a specific reason. I just need a way to print the name of the biggest variable.

Comment: You could define all your variables as part of an object, then loop over the key value pairs to find the max. I'm not sure if there is a way to get the variable name as a string

Comment: This seems like a total XY problem. Can you expand on what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: One improvement can be using `if..., else if... else` instead of 4 `if`s

Comment: @Rajesh - having an else doesn't make any sense, the conditions are against different variables

Comment: If first if returns true, still code will evaluate all `if`s.

Comment: why you want to do this is important, because it typically a code smell that indicates a poor design decision or approach to a problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about working code and belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com. *it is opinion based as well as the variety of quality of answers indicates*

Comment: This may be a good question for [codereview.se], so long as: **(A)** _the code works_, **and (B)** _it's not hypothetical or incomplete in any way_. Please read the [on-topic guide](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before posting, if you choose to go to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). If you have any questions or concerns, join us at our [CR Help Desk](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34045).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

One way, if you cannot use object, then get max value and then check individual values to variable. Here you will not have very complex condition. Also its better to `if...else if...else` than multiple `if`

```js
a = 55;
b = 13;
c = 45;
d = 5;

var max = Math.max(a,b,c,d);
var varName = "";

if(max === a){
  varName = "a";
}
else if(max === b){
  varName = "b";
}
else if(max === c){
  varName = "c";
}
else{
  varName = d;
}

alert(varName);
```

Comment: @xRobot - you realize this is no better and in my opinion **worse** than what you were already doing because it doing the same work twice now.

Comment: @JarredRoberson, kindly suggest a better way to do this, if user doesn't have an option of using objects. I already have mentioned, **if you cannot use object** which means object method is an ideal approach. But sometimes our code is not in best shape and needs patch work.

Comment: **This is terrible advice to give to someone that does not understand why what they are trying to do is wrong and what correct approaches would be. This is in no way close to anything that could be considered a *correct* approach.**

Answer (score 2):

### You can't get the variable name directly:

> Very few languages support what you want to do because the variable
>   names only exist for your benefit in the source code. They do not
>   exist in the compiled executable code in that form anymore and
>   tracking them would be  extremely expensive.
>
> If you want to do this, **there is something fundamentally wrong with your design** as there is no reason that would preclude doing it the most idiomatic way possible which is to use an [*associative array*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array), which in JavaScript means using an [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Objects_and_maps_compared) or an actual [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) when available and where appropriate.

---

### Object based approach:

Most compatible way if you do not have access to [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map):

You can use an object and find the property name. The most concise way to do this is with the [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function.

```
var obj = {a:55,b:13,c:45,d:5};

var maxPropertyName = Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(previous,key){
    return obj[previous] > obj[key] ? previous : key;
})

console.log(maxPropertyName);
```

#### Output:

```
a
```

---

### Map based approach:

For this case a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) seems more appropriate since this looks like a homogeneous`Collection` rather than a `Type` of something.

> Map instances are only useful for collections, and
>   you should consider adapting your code where you have previously used
>   objects for such. Objects shall be used as records, with fields and
>   methods. If you're still not sure which one to use, ask yourself the
>   following questions:
>
> - Are keys usually unknown until run time, **do you need to look them
>     up dynamically**?
> - Do all values have the same type, and can be used interchangeably?
>     Do you need keys that aren't strings?
> - Are key-value pairs often added or removed? Do you have an
>     arbitrary (easily changing) amount of key-value pairs?
> - **Is the collection iterated?** Those all are signs that you want a Map
>     for a collection.
>
> If in contrast you have a fixed amount of keys, operate on them
>   individually, and distinguish between their usage, then you want an
>   object.

#### Here is how to add a `.reduce()` method to [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map):

```
Map.prototype.reduce = function(callback){
    'use strict';
    if (this == null) {
      throw new TypeError('Array.prototype.reduce called on null or undefined');
    }
    if (typeof callback !== 'function') {
      throw new TypeError(callback + ' is not a function');
    }
    var t = Object(this), value;
    if (t.size === 0) { value = undefined; }
    else if (t.size === 1) { value = t.keys().next().value; }
    else {
      value = t.keys().next().value;
      for (var kv of t) {
          value = callback(value, kv[0]);
      }
    }
    return value;
};
```

#### Same `.reduce()` code now works:

```
var m = new Map([["a",55],["b",13], ["c",45],["d",5]]);

var maxPropertyName = m.reduce(function(previous,key){
    return m.get(previous) > m.get(key) ? previous : key;
})
console.log(maxPropertyName);
```

#### Output:

```
a
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do it, store everything in an object and loop over the keys:

```js
// you can keep the input variables
var a = 55;
var b = 13;
var c = 45;
var d = 5;

var obj = {
  a: a,
  b: b,
  c: c,
  d: d
}

var max;
var varName;

Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
  if (!max || max < obj[key]) {
    max = obj[key];
    varName = key;
  }
});

snippet.log(max);
snippet.log(varName);
```

```html
<script src="https://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function high(obj) {
    var highest = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY,
      keyName = null;
    for (var key in obj) {
      if( obj[key] > highest ) {
        highest = obj[key];
        keyName = key;
      }
    }
  return keyName;
}
```

Comment: *I need a way to get the name of the variable* - this does not get names

Comment: @lucianandrei It returns the last key in obj not the one with the max value.

Comment: @ShanShan yes, fixed now, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score -1):

In this way you can need not care about the variable name.Also need not repeat the variable name.

```
// init 
var obj={};
var max=0,maxName="";
var x={};
for(var key in window){
  x[key]=window[key];
}

// your code
a = 55;
b = 13;
c = 45;
d = 5;
// end of your code

// select the max num 
for(var key in window){
  if(typeof(window[key]) == "number" && typeof(x[key])!="number"){
   if(window[key]>max){
     max=window[key];
     maxName=key;
   }
  }
}
// output the variable name
console.log(maxName);
```

And you can write a method to reuse：

```
function getTop(func){
    // init
    var obj={};
    var max=0,maxName="";
    var x={};
    for(var key in window){
      x[key]=window[key];
    }
    func();
    // select the max num
    for(var key in window){
      if(typeof(window[key]) == "number" && typeof(x[key])!="number"){
       if(window[key]>max){
         max=window[key];
         window[key]=undefined;
         maxName=key;
       }
      }
    }
    // output the variable name
    return maxName;
}
```

you can use the code to get the top varname:

```
var top=getTop(function(){
a=11;
b=22;
c=23;
d=14;
});
```